# Installing applications to a different drive having more space, other than the one containing the home directory for ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD.

Now I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 in my SSD. The problem is as the SSD does not have much space and I deal with a lot of huge applications, it is impossible to have enough storage space.
Is it possible to install applications in the 1TB HDD and how?

Comment: 1TB SSDs are getting very inexpensive https://www.google.com/search?q=1TB+SSD&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS804US804&oq=1TB+SSD

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Linux system files on the SSD to keep your computer running fast. However mount your HDD to your filesystem then run your large programs off the HDD.

Here's help for automounting your HDD: https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup

And for manual mounting: https://superuser.com/questions/467170/how-do-i-mount-internal-hdds-in-ubuntu-via-the-command-line

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.

I was able to mount the HDD but the part where you told  to run my large programs off the HDD, that's where I am stuck.

Eg. I do a lot of Machine learning work and in windows I had all my games and other support apps installed in my HDD while only the OS and some important work related apps were in the SSD.
Is there any way to emulate that in Linux?